# Can I get impact-js to work in IE7 and/or 8 using excanvas or a similar canvas shim?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm investigating if it's possible to use this game engine outside of IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need more than a canvas shim. Impact also relies on the audio tag, addEventListener and a slew of other standards compliant stuff ie8 does not provide.

Even if you could shim them all into IE 8 it's quite possible that impact could just ignore your shims and fail anyway.

[here is a thread detailing support on ie8](http://impactjs.com/forums/impact-engine/web-testing-of-my-game-some-good-news-some-bad-news/page/1) from the website itself.